# is there a mathematical explanation of precision and recall tradeoff?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Is there a mathematical explanation of precision and recall tradeoff? Ie, is it possible
mathematically to see that as you increase one, the other decreases?

$\text{Precision}=\frac{TP}{P^*}=\frac{TP}{TP+FP}$

$\text{Recall}=\frac{TP}{P}=\frac{TP}{TP+FN}$.

When precision increases, why does Recall decease?

Comment: no, you can have definitely perfect precision and perfect recall

Comment: but in almost all ML material, they mention this tradeoff.

Comment: because you can have ideally the perfect classifier that nails both of them, but we don't have it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mentioned so called precision and recall tradeoff is a statistical tendency on average, not a mathematical necessity which can be easily shown in below example.

Let $TP=10, FP=5, FN=5$ for demonstration purposes of a trained (non-optimal) classifier, then $$\text{precision} = 10/(10+5) \approx 0.67, \text{recall} = 10/(10+5) \approx 0.67$$

Now let's say we improved the classifier to increase its precision by reducing false positives while keeping true positives constant, ie, now $TP=10, FP=2, FN=5$, then $$\text{precision} = 10/(10+2) \approx 0.83, \text{recall} = 10/(10+5) \approx 0.67$$

Thus recall *remains the same* despite precision increases in this case. Usually you can define a single [F-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score) as weighted harmonic mean of both precision and recall to tradeoff and effectively weigh the lower of the two numbers more heavily.

Answer (score 3):

The tradeoff between precision and recall occurs because increasing the threshold for classification will result in fewer false positives (increasing precision) but also more false negatives (decreasing recall), and vice versa. You cannot eliminate both false positives and false negatives simultaneously without the presence of a perfect classifier, so improving one often comes at the cost of the other.

But you can do is picking the best threshold for the trade-off from what you have. For example:

You can calculate Youden's J statistic $J = TPR - FPR$ for finding threshold:

```
J = tpr - fpr
# Get the index of the maximum J statistic
max_j_index = np.argmax(J)
# Get the best threshold value
best_threshold_j = thresholds[max_j_index]
```